SQL query execution using python
I am attempting to extract an SQL query using Streamlit in Python. The user inputs the query in an input box, it executes, and displays the output. I want to log both the questions and queries. After displaying the result, I want to add a thumbs-down button. There should be a function to store the log separately in another folder. Currently, when clicking the thumbs-down button, logging is not happening, and it reloads the page, storing empty.
import streamlit as st
import psycopg2
import datetime
import os

def run_sql(query):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            database='postgres',
            user='postgres',
            password='postgresql',
            host='localhost',
            port='5432'
        )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        value_sql = cursor.fetchone()[0]  # Fetch one row, one column
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
    
        return value_sql
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"Error: {e}")
        return None

def save_feedback(feedback):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    folder_name = "feedback"
    os.makedirs(folder_name, exist_ok=True)
    filename = f"data_{current_time}.txt"
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
    
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(feedback)

def main():
    st.set_page_config(page_title="SQL")
    st.title("SQL Query")
    question = st.text_input("Enter your SQL query")
    
    if st.button("Run Query"):
        answer = run_sql(question)
        if answer is not None:
            st.write("Result:", answer)
            if st.button(""):
                save_feedback(answer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Clicking the thumbs-down button should not reload the page; instead, it should log the details.

If you want to save both the query and answer, save_feedback() should have two parameters, not just one.
